# Is there any code like "If the storyboard ID is XXX, then..." in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am now building an app which needs to load two different URLs inside two `UIView Controllers` a `UIWebView`. Though, they need to be in same classes. So is there any way that I can simply check "If the storyboard ID is XXX, then load URL_1, else URL_2"?

Here is my code:

```
let day_url = NSURL(string: "http://www.url1.com/")
let day_url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: day_url!)
day_webView.loadRequest(day_url_request)


let week_url = NSURL(string: "http://www.url2.com/")
let week_url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: week_url!)
week_webView.loadRequest(week_url_request)
```

Thanks!

PS: Sorry for my bad English. :(

[image: Two View Controller in 1 class but 2 IDs]

Comment: They can't be in the same class. You need to create two separate classes for each `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your `UIViewController`s has an unique ID and a custom class. The first `UIViewController` should look something like this:

```
class StoryboardID1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let day_url = NSURL(string: "http://www.url1.com/")
        let day_url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: day_url!)
        day_webView.loadRequest(day_url_request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

And for the second `UIViewController` we have:

```
class StoryboardID2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let week_url = NSURL(string: "http://www.url2.com/")
        let week_url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: week_url!)
        week_webView.loadRequest(week_url_request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**The other way**

First, declare your `UIViewController`:

```
let myViewControllerID = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PutIDHere") as UIViewController
```

Then check if `myViewControllerID` is actually the controller the user navigating at:

```
if segue.identifier == "myViewControllerID" {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use restorationIdentifier instead of Storyboard identifier and check it from

```
if self.restorationIdentifier == "View1" {
     // load URL1
} else {
     // Load URL2
}
```

Good Luck